Can you still use a plug if the third prong is reattached to it properly
The third prong of my plug broke off, but I reattached it. Can I still use it.

how did you reattach it?

Somehow I doubt you "reattached the broken prong properly", for instance, in a manner that UL or ETL would approve of.

The only way to answer that is with detailed knowledge of how the pin became detached, and how you re-attached it. ie If you repaired it appropriately, its fine, by definition. If, as we all suspect, you bodged it in some way, then it is very not fine.
Also - are we talking mains leccy here, or just some low-voltage signal cable?

It’s a plug for a computer, and I was able to reattach the third prong by pushing it back into its place.

Are you sure that the wire that was attached to it is secure? How do you know?

Are you willing to risk frying your computer vs spending $£€2 for a replacement plug or ~20 for a whole new cable?

You didn't reattach it. You reinserted it. The latter doesn't establish a reliable electrical path.

Lack of correct grounding prong may cause electrical device to become energized.  Which means if you, your small child, fido, or kitty come in contact with an energized device they will get a shock.  Play with fire, eventually will get burned or in this case play with electricity eventually you will get shocked.

Get a new plug.
Pushing the third prong back in will just make a bad connection that will fall out.

And possibly get the grounding pin stuck in the receptacle which would, most likely, result in replacing the receptacle. Thus a bad situation gets worse.

Echoing the choir. Get a new plug. Especially if you like your computer.
If you don't have a grounding plug connected to your computer it is possible for a static charge to build up on your computer that will end up frying some of the components.
Replacement plugs/wires are inexpensive. Don't be cheap. Fix the it correctly.
